# generate number sequence from consecutive number

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where I am getting the consecutive numbers 0,20,40,60,80...
I want to generate 1,2,3,4,5

If I get 0 then generate 1
If 20 then generate 2 and  so on..

right now I am doing like :

```
function generateSequence(consecutiveSequence)
{
  if(consecutiveSequence === 0)
  {
    console.log(1)
  }
  else
  {
    console.log(consecutiveSequence / 10);
  }
}
```

But this doesn't give me correct sequence

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Javascript or C? Please figure out the language you want to write your code in, and tag appropriately

Comment: I seems like you could just simply count the numbers and save that in an array... If you get the numbers in js (e.g an array), you can iterate over the length and save the index +1 in a seperate array. But is it js or c? It's kind of a big difference...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the desired result this would work in the given case:

```js
var array = [];                               // Global array
   
function generateNumber(item) {              // function called on every item
    array[array.length] = array.length + 1;  // array.length will be longer each iteration 
    console.log(array);
}

var num = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80];
num.forEach(function (e) {
    generateNumber(e);
});
```

I don't really get how the sequence is supposed to work though, the first two numbers are generated right by your algorithm, the others would need a (x / 2) for it to work...

Comment: I wont get 0,20,40 as an array rather will get it one by one so that i will pass it to the function generateSequence

Comment: I changed the snippet so it would work like you desired

Comment: @sarveshshukla is this what you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `forEach` loop like this:

```
var arr = [0,20,40,60,80];

arr.forEach((element, index) => {
  arr[index] = index + 1;
});

console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I wont get 0,20,40 as an array rather will get it one by one so that i will pass it to the function generateSequence

Comment: You can keep some kind of container (array in your case) to keep track of the number that you receive. When you get `0`, you push it to the `[]` and get the value you want as the index of that number you just received + 1.